# Product admin page breaking with too many product variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

When adding more than 100-155 variations to a variable product our admin page seems to break and loose all it's layout and i'm not able to edit anything to do with the product. Some of our products are going to contain around 500 variations but can't figure out why this is happening.

Any advice would be greatly received.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a client site which turned out to be a php POST variable limit (1000) which is an attempt for PHP to solve some security issues. This can be easily changed via the php.ini config file ex:
max_input_vars = 5000

you should also note the `max_input_nesting_level`

But we ended up using a grouped products instead of variations.